# No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.io/setup for getting started instructions

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, flutter-test

i am using the Android Studion 3.3 on Windows 10. i have created a emulator and it is running manually for the AVD manager but when i Click on Run Button the fallowing messageBox sappers

**> No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.io/setup for getting started instructions.**

Comment: i tested my app from the Command Promt, the app run well but the Android studio didn't show ?? help me to get it out

Comment: If you have additional information, please [edit] your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to restart your adb deamon first. Adb is the program that runs in the background to install your application to the simulator. You can do that by using the following command:

```
adb kill-server
```

Then you can run `adb devices`. If should start adb again and if it shows your emulator, it means that the simulator is sucessfully connected to adb, which means you are ready to try to install the application again from Android Studio.

If that still does not work, you can also restart Android Studio and the emulator, which often solves this kind of problems for me. (It's also useful if you run `flutter doctor`, it will tell you if any devices are connected).

Comment: but the emulator is running but the flutter app is not showing any Emulator

Comment: Did you restart the emulator and the 'flutter app'?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?